# How to create input fields for a hash storing multiple values in a database column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I'm trying to store multiple values using a hash in a database column for "text" in an object called Overlays.

So calling it looks like overlay.text

There are multiple values I want to store in the text column, such as..

• Preheadline
• Bullet1
• Bullet2
• Bullet3

I'm serializing the text column in the model

```
class Overlay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
  serialize :text
```

Then, in a form for creating a model, I've tried creating an input field for "Bullet1", but it's not storing the value.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="col-xs-12 field-title">Bullet 1</h4>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="overlay[text][bullet1]"     placeholder="Bullet point text here" class="form-control input-lg" value="<%= @overlay.text[:bullet1] if defined? @overylay.text and @overlay.text[:bullet1].present? %>" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

And I'm trying to get the value to display like so..

```
<span style="display: block; margin-top: -15px; margin-left: 25px;"><% if @overlay.text and @overlay.text[:bullet1].present? %><%= @overlay.text[:bullet1] %><% else %>this should not show<% end %>
          </span>
```

So far, I've had no luck getting the value "Bullet1" to save in the text database column.

Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Well. What's the DB engine you are using ?

Comment: Did you generate a migration for the `text` column already?

Comment: @EthanDenney use `hstore` as a column data type ..... if possible.. then life is easy..